# What's the best way to add cells to gridView?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-gridview, android-cursoradapter

I have a fairly standard content provider + cursorAdapter + gridview setup. The issue is that I need to add 2 cells to one particular gridview in my app. My client's design has the 2 final cells in the grid being "Add from different category" and "Create New". This are "stickers" that are organized into categories. Everywhere else in the app these cells should not show.

My initial thought was to figure out a way to modify the adapter to add these, but I couldn't find a way.

My current thought is to kinda "cheat" the info into the data with the sqlite calls... maybe with a temp table? I'm sure I could do this given enough time, but I'm under the gun so instead of wasting a lot of time I thought I would ask here if anyone knows the best way to do this?

**TL;DR**

What is the best/easiest way to add static cells to a `CursorAdapter` backed `gridView`?

---

P.S. This is such a generic question I didn't think code was needed, but if you can think of any that would help please ask!

Comment: try to add your static info to list data after getting from db in data fetch method from db.

Comment: Wrap the current data cursor in a CursorWrapper and override its methods to return the two extra cells besides the cursor data.

Comment: Awesome! Ended up going with Haresh's solution using `MatrixCursor` and then using `MergeCursor` to merge them in. Would you mind posting an answer so I can accept it?^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I did it:

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {

    //add static fields
    MatrixCursor extras = new MatrixCursor(ObjectDao.getAllCollumns());
    extras.addRow(new String[] { "-1","0","0","0","","","","", "Add Existing","1","0","-1","-1" });
    extras.addRow(new String[] { "-2","0","0","0","","","","", "Add New","1","0","-1","-2" });
    Cursor[] cursors = { data, extras };

    if (adapter != null) {
        adapter.swapCursor(new MergeCursor(cursors));
    }
}
```